# Odoo table in postgresql is larger than others MySQL/Oracle/MSSQL database table?

Tags: database, postgresql, odoo

I just wondering following situation in postgresql db.

This case happen in Odoo ERP postgresql db below:

**Total Record Count in Purchase Order : 1457 

Total Table Size of Purchase Order   : 966 MB**

There has no bytea data inside table.

Please let me know/share why this is happen or it is normal situation?

Comment: This impossible to answer without seeing the structure of the `purchase_order` table. How did you calculate the size of the table? And how did you calculate the size of the table in the other database products? And how much larger (supposedly) is the Postgres table? Does a `vacuum full` shrink the table size?

Comment: I used to measure by using query below: SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size('purchase_order')); . Do you think number of counts and size should be or not? There has 36 columns inside that table.

Comment: I am not trying to comparing with others. I need to understand this is normal case or not.

Comment: `pg_total_relation_size()` includes the size of the table plus the size of **all** indexes. Did you do that on the other databases as well? And if you don't try to compare then why do you have a "larger than others" in the question?

Comment: I used vaccum full command for that table and table size become 968 kb. Thanks alot  :) Can you please share why we have to use vacuum? Normally postgresql has autovacuum right? (But i am not sure, just confirm like db professional like you ).

Comment: If someone ask me in oracle, the table is not large like that. At that time i need answer :) However, thanks you :)

Answer (score 2):

Since the table shrunk considerably when you ran `VACUUM (FULL)` on it, it was *bloated*, that is, it had a lot of free space or "dead tuples" in it.

There are many reasons why this can happen:

- Autovacuum is configured to run too slowly.
- There are so many `UPDATE`s that create "dead tuples" that autovacuum cannot keep up.
- Something, like an open transaction, a replication slot or a prepared transaction is keeping autovacuum from removing old table rows.
- Explicit `LOCK TABLE` statements interrup autovacuum all the time.
- ...

You'll have to investigate and fix the cause of the problem. If in doubt, hire a consultant.